# Deleting pkgs file from Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

So I was unsuccessful in installing Anaconda as it would get stuck on the "setting up the package cache" indefinitely.

Another thread on here suggested just installing an older version. I figured before I do that I should delete everything in the Anaconda3 folder first. Since it didn't finish installing I don't have the anaconda prompt, so I tried just manually deleting everything in there using the file explorer. However the pkgs folder is huge and says it would take over a day to recycle everything.

Haven't found any resources for this specific situation so not sure what to do. Do I even need to delete these if I want to reinstall?

Comment: Sounds like you are on windows. Don't recycle, but delete permanently. Should go much faster

Comment: @FlyingTeller How do I permanently delete without the anaconda prompt? Pressing 'delete' in windows just recycles them. Do you think I can reinstall with that pkgs folder still in there?

Comment: Use shift+delete